# Doubling a number

Tags: c

I have to make a program that calculates the double of a number. For example, if I insert `2` in `cmd`, the program should return `4`. I was already given a starter program with a `sum` function included, and I have to complete it.

I tried many things, like clean all `y`'s and insert twice instead of summing, but like I said I'm a noob.

This is the program without any changes :

```
// Sum, recursive, using only elementary operations
#include <stdio.h>
int sum(int x, int y)
{
 return y == 0 ? x : sum(x+1, y-1);
}
int main(void)
{
 int x;
 int y;
 scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
 int z = sum(x, y);
 printf("%d\n", z);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What part is it that you don't understand? Write this program without any recursion first, get it working, then take it from there.

Comment: Maybe clean up your question title? Much of it can either go into the body text or just be deleted.

Comment: @Lundin I imagine the recursive `sum` function was part of the code given to OP, and thus can't be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your description you say that you need to take **one** input. However, your program reads **two** inputs.

Maybe this is what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum(int x, int y)
{
 return y == 0 ? x : sum(x+1, y-1);
}
int main(void)
{
 int x;
 if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1)  // Only 1 input
 {
    // Input error
    return -1;
 }
 int z = sum(x, x);    // Use x for both arguments
 printf("%d\n", z);
 return 0;
}
```

This works because the `sum` functions increments one argument and decrements the other in the recursive call and continues doing that until one of the arguments reach zero. In this way the end result will be `2 * x`

Let's say the input is 3. Then you'll have these calls:

```
sum(3, 3)
sum(4, 2)
sum(5, 1)
sum(6, 0) // Which will end the recursion and return 6 all the way up
```

Comment: @ImDumb When you use `scanf` you must always check that you the correct number of scanned values. If not you need some error handling. In this example I just return a negative value to tell that the program failed.